# Laravel seeder : Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Notification::getConnectionName()

Tags: php, laravel, factory

I have a many to many relationship between two models:

#### User

```php
namespace App\Models;


class User extends Model
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable,hasFactory;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    ];

}
```

#### Notification

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Notification extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    use HasFactory;
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

 
}
```

I created a `factory` for each model and a `Seeder` which calls the two factories in order to create `users` and attach notifications to each one of them.

#### NotificationUserSeeder:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Notification;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class MockNotificationUser extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */


    }
}
```

I am getting this error when running `db:seed`:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Notifications\Notification::getConnectionName()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have named model name as `Notification` .And while importing in seeder class ,it look like you have imported

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
```

instead of

```
use App\Models\Notification;
```

**Updated**
The issue is with User model due to conflict in model name and  Illuminate Notification facade's. Notification  facade not used in User model so better to remove notification import. Suppose if you are using Notification illuminate then you can use as alias any one of the imports

Comment: How would call my class if i remove it's import then

Comment: can you show NotificationUserSeeder full code

Comment: yes please check the code now it's updated

Comment: remove this import use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification; from User model since you are not using

Comment: i am asking from user model .not notification seeder

Comment: if still error let me know i can help you to fix

Comment: your answer is correct , it fixed it thank you so much

Comment: @needgfasap.glad to here ,you have solved your issue